# how to traverse div element inside div element in jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make ajax search bar in jquery.I am struck at one place.I have created dynamic div element inside one big div element means div created along with the json response.I want to traverse div elements once user inputs something then it should be traversed via key up and down arrow.

```
<div class="comment">
      <div class="single" >
          //this div is dynamically created with the information 
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to highlight the item inside div element with the help of key up and key down.
What can be the possible way.I have tried 2-3 ways but that are not useful.

**EDIT** 
Here is what I have tried

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#inputText').on('keydown',function(e){ 
      var $current=$('.comment>.single').first(); 
      $current.css('background-color','yellow'); 
      if(e.keyCode==40){ 
         var $nextDiv; 
         if($current.next().size==0){ 
            $nextDiv=$('.comment>.single').first(); 
          } 
         else
          { 
             $nextDiv=$current.next(); 
          }
          $current.css('background-color',''); 
          $nextDiv.css('background-color','yellow'); 
          $current=$nextDiv; 
         } 
      }); 
   });
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what are the 2-3 ways that you have tried?

Comment: i have tried using filter,first function. but i can easily highlight 2div and rest div element but i am struck at first div when user press down 1 time from input  box then  it should highlight first then it should move rest along .

Comment: post your code here... people won't be able to help without seeing what you are trying to do

Comment: I post the jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not setting your current div and next div properly, also you have not shown your code for arrow down

well here is a jsFiddle that I have put for you

https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/1/

also you need to check if any of your div has a background color of yellow and traverse accordingly

i have looped through all the elements with class of '.single' there is a better way to do this

```
var a = $('.single');
       for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       {
       if($(a[i]).css('backgroundColor') == "rgb(255, 255, 0)")
       {
      isFirst = false;
            $current= $(a[i]);
          break;
       }
       else{
       isFirst = true;
       $current = $('.comment > .single').first();
       }
       }
```

and then based on the arrow pressed selected next or previous element

```
if($current.next().size==0){ 
            $nextDiv=$('.comment>.single').first(); 
          } 
          if(!isFirst){
          $nextDiv=$current.next(); 
          $current.css('background-color',''); 
          $nextDiv.css('background-color','yellow'); 
          $current=$nextDiv; 
          }
          else
          {
          $current.css('background-color','yellow'); 
          }
```

and

```
 var $nextDiv; 
         if($current.prev().size==0){ 
            $nextDiv=$('.comment>.single').first(); 
          } 
          if(!isFirst){
          $nextDiv=$current.prev(); 
          $current.css('background-color',''); 
          $nextDiv.css('background-color','yellow'); 
          $current=$nextDiv; 
          }
          else
          {
          $current.css('background-color','yellow'); 
          }
```

Comment: you can mark it as answer if you find this is correct.

Comment: i have one doubt when i go(your case)to after 4 down key then at 5th key it does not highlight anything  instead it should highlight first key(first div).

Comment: updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/2/ you can do this similarly for key up

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input', $('#comment')).each(function () {

$('input', $('#single')).each(function () {

    console.log($(this)); //log every element found to console output
});

    console.log($(this)); //log every element found to console output
});
```

Comment: i dont want to all information.I just want when user press down key then it should highlight the div which is closest.(highlight only when down key press)